# Error while running spring test on circleCI

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, circleci

I am new to circleCI and i want to run some spring's tests, so far this is my config.yml file:

```
# Use the latest 2.1 version of CircleCI pipeline process engine.
# See: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference
version: 2.1

# Define a job to be invoked later in a workflow.
# See: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#jobs
jobs:
  spring-test:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/openjdk:17.0.1
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: "spring tests"
          working_directory: ./spring/test/
          command: "./gradlew test"

# Invoke jobs via workflows
# See: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#workflows
workflows:
  say-hello-workflow:
    jobs:
      - spring-test
```

But when i run it i get this exceptions on each tests:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804
            Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException at AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275
                Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException at DialectFactoryImpl.java:100
```

I run those test on local and i passed it. I was trying to follow this [guide](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-java/) but i could not make it works.

This spring app use postgres as data base, this is the application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1234
```